# Sum of Poisson variables through factorizing

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, independence, binomial-distribution

This might be similar to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508190/independence-of-random-variables-by-guessing), however I don't see how to use the same logic here. I've recently came across the fact that the sum of $X\sim \text{Po}(\gamma)$ and  $Y\sim \text{Po}(\delta)$ (if they are independent) has the distribution $\text{Po}(\gamma + \delta)$ and also that
$$P(X= k | X+Y = n) = \text{Bi}( n, \gamma/(\gamma+\delta); k) \quad n\in \mathbb N_0, k=0, \dots, n$$
which was proven by showing that
$$P(X=k, X+Y = n) = \text{Po}(\gamma + \delta; n) \text{Bi}(n, \gamma/ (\gamma + \delta); k)$$
i.e. "splitting" the joint probability into $P(X+Y=n)$ and $P(X=k|X+Y=n)$.

My main question is: How did we *prove* statement? That is how do we know that what we really found is the factorization into $P(X+Y=n)P(X=k|X+Y=n)$ and haven't just "accidentally" stumbled across the expression for a Poisson and Binomial probability in the expression.

**edit**: Possibly a (much) better way of asking is: we know that
$$P(X+Y=n)P(X=k|X+Y=n)=\text{Po}(\gamma + \delta; n) \text{Bi}(n, \gamma/ (\gamma + \delta); k)$$
But how do we know that 
$$P(X+Y=n) = \text{Po}(\gamma + \delta; n)$$
$$P(X=k|X+Y=n)= \text{Bi}(n, \gamma/ (\gamma + \delta); k)$$

Comment: Maybe you could be interested by a recent answer I gave to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1985028); this answer deals with the fact that it is possible to find back binomial distribution from Poisson distribution, in the  framework of Poisson *processes*.

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks, this question in fact even is from a text about the poisson point process, however I don't think that helps me - what I am after is understanding why this factorization is sufficient for the proof, the factorization itself is simple enough (and so I didn't include it, as it is irrelevant)

Comment: Is the heart of the question the way you interpret conditionned distributions ?

Comment: Well, essentially my question is - we've managed to show that $P(X=k, X+Y=n)$ equals to an expression that factorizes to a product of "some Poisson" and "some Binomial" probability. How can we infer from that the conclusions of the theorem?

Comment: You see that the former factor is independent of $k$, so you may try to sum the expression from $k = 0$ to $k = n$ (from the conditional probability it is trivial that $k$ can only take values in $\{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$)

Comment: @BGM Oh right, thank you, almost there! How do I now seethe other equality (i.e. the binomial one)? Perhaps it should be obvious, but it isn't to me. (by the way feel free to turn this into an answer, as you're answering exactly to what I am asking)

Comment: @BGM Nevermind, now it is obvious even to me :) Still, it'd be nice if you turn this into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on [BGM](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/297308/bgm)'s comment.

We start with this equality
$$P(X+Y=n)P(X=k|X+Y=n)=\text{Po}(\gamma + \delta; n) \text{Bi}(n, \gamma/ (\gamma + \delta); k)$$

Since one of the expressions on each side does not depend on $k$, we can sum both sides w.r.t. $k$ to obtain that
$$P(X+Y=n) \sum^{n}_{k=0} P(X=k|X+Y = n) = \text{Po}(\gamma + \delta; n) \sum^n_{k=0} \text{Bi}(n, \gamma/(\gamma + \delta); k)$$
Both sums equal one since we're summing over the whole distribution, yielding
$$P(X+Y=n) = \text{Po}(\gamma + \delta; n)$$
Dividing both sides of the original expression by $\text{Po}(\gamma + \delta; n)$ yields
$$P(X = k | X+Y = n) = \text{Bi}(n, \gamma/ (\gamma + \delta); k)$$

Comment: Glad to see you grab it quickly. Sorry I was busy before to revisit the post. As long as you got pass it then it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate $P(X+Y=n)$ we use the convolution formula:

$P(X+Y=n)=\sum_{x=0}^n f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(n-x)$

$$P(X+Y=n)=\sum_{x=0}^n e^{-\gamma} \cdot \frac{\gamma^x}{x!}\cdot e^{-\delta} \cdot \frac{\delta^{n-x}}{(n-x)!}  $$

$$P(X+Y=n)=\sum_{x=0}^n e^{-\gamma-\delta} \cdot  \gamma^x \cdot \delta^{n-x} \cdot \frac{1}{x!(n-x)!}  $$

$e^{-\gamma-\delta}$ can be factored out.

If $\frac{1}{x!(n-x)!}$ is multiplied by $n!$ then it becomes the binomial coefficient $n \choose x$

$$n!\cdot P(X+Y=n)=e^{-\gamma-\delta}\cdot \sum_{x=0}^n  {n \choose x}\cdot \gamma^x \cdot \delta^{n-x}    $$

Applying the binomial theorem the sum becomes $(\gamma + \delta)^n$

Thus $n!\cdot P(X+Y=n)=e^{-\gamma-\delta}\cdot (\gamma + \delta)^n$

$ P(X+Y=n)=e^{-\gamma-\delta}\cdot \frac{(\gamma + \delta)^n}{n!}$

$P(X+Y=n)=Poi(\gamma+\delta, n)$

---

---

> My main question is: How did we *prove* statement? That is how do we
>   know that what we really found is the factorization into
>   $P(X+Y=n)P(X=k|X+Y=n)$

Let $A$ be the event that $X+Y=n$. And $B$ the event that $X=k$

You want to split $P(A\cap B)$. For this purpose you use the multiplication rule for dependent events.

$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A)$

Comment: I've edited the question, since it seems that I am not conveying the source of my confusion well enough.

Comment: @DahnJahn I have made an edit.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer since it *is* useful, however the thing is one does not need to do this calculation at all, from the statement in the question it is directly observable, as BGM points out in the comment. I will probably write out the answer myself, since he doesn't seem to be interested in turning the comment in an answer.

Comment: @DahnJahn I thought that the question, like I had understood, was still current. But luckily the answer was in some way helpful.